# How can I use the background property using Javascript instead of using <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load an image background inside a specific div instead of `<img src="">` tag using Javascript.

As it is now the code with the `<img/>` tag is:

```
item.prepend($('<img/>', {src: file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + '' +file[options.pathAttribute]}));
```

I tried something like that:

```
item.prepend($('<div style="background:url('file[options.baseUrlAttribute] + ''      
+file[options.pathAttribute]}')no-repeat center center / cover"></div>' ));
```

But it doesn't work and returns an error.

What is the correct syntax to make it work?

Comment: can you tell us what the resulting html is? From the looks of it, you're creating an empty div, and prepending it to an item, so it won't have any height.

Comment: item.prepend($('<div style="background:url(' + file[options.baseUrlAttribute]     
+file[options.pathAttribute]+')no-repeat center center / cover"></div>' ));

Comment: @Kinglish this worked fine can you post it as answer so i can select it as the worked answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to miss typos in long concatenated statements. The fixed code is:

```
item.prepend($('<div style="background:url(' + file[options.baseUrlAttribute] +file[options.pathAttribute]+')no-repeat center center / cover"></div>' ));
```

Or broken down for easier reading

```
const url = file[options.baseUrlAttribute] +file[options.pathAttribute] ;
const tag = '<div style="background:url(' + url + ')no-repeat center center / cover"></div>';
item.prepend(tag);
```